# How to use two echo commands to print data on one line using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Below is the code I'm using to find users created date and last logon date which is then written to a .csv file.

```
$users=Get-ADuser -SearchBase "OU=testou1,dc=US,dc=ITOPS,dc=COM" -Filter * -properties samaccountname,lastlogondate,Created    
$forloop = foreach($user in $users) {    
         echo $user.samaccountname    
          echo $user.created    
        echo $user.lastlogondate    
        }    
$forloop | Out-file c:\bin\exporting.csv -Append
```

This code prints each item on a new line like this:

```
username  
created date  
last logon date
```

But I want it all on the same line with different columns:

```
username createdDate lastLogonDate
```

Comment: Good morning!  In order to receive help here you really need to post code that shows us what you have already tried.  What you have posted here is really a request for someone else to write the script that you need. :(

Comment: @DavidHoelzer the code is in the question. `echo 'hai'; echo 'hello'` I think he has a clear issue. Perhaps it is a dup but all the components are there.

Comment: We really need to know what is provoking the question. Tell the problem you want to solve, now _how_ you think you need to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create an an array of objects with name and value properties. That will export nicely to CSV.

Bear in mind I'm writing this on a phone, I'll check it in my ISE later, but I've  amended your code below:

```
$users=Get-ADuser -SearchBase "OU=testou1,dc=US,dc=ITOPS,dc=COM" -Filter * -properties samaccountname,lastlogondate,Created    

$array = @() #declare the array outside the loop

$forloop = foreach($user in $users) {    
$arrayrow = New-Object System.Object
     $arrayrow | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name User -value $user.samaccountname    
      $arrayrow | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Created -value  $user.created    
    $arrayrow | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name LastLogonDate -value $user.lastlogondate    
  $array += $arrayrow
    }    
$array | export-csv  -notype c:\bin\exporting.csv
```

Comment: its working perfectly fine and im getting output as required.. thanks a lot. As im very new to powershell,can you please explain function of the terms $array and $arraynow clearly so that i can reuse them. and in the above code is $forloop still required?

Comment: Glad that done the trick for you. First of all, you don't need to keep the `$forloop = ` but as you've seen it does no harm, the `foreach` code after it still runs fine.  $array and $arrayrow are both just variables that could be named however you want, I just used names that remind you what they are for.

Comment: To create an empty array just assign a variable the value `@()` - special syntax in powershell. To create an object you assign a variable the value `New-Object System.Object`. You add properties to the object by piping (`|`) the variable to the `Add-Member` cmdlet, specifying type `NoteProperty`, a name and then a value. Finally to add the object to the array using the `+=` operator. It adds what is on the right of it to whatever is on the left.

Answer (score 3):

Just so you know `echo` in PowerShell is actually an alias for `Write-Output`.

```
PS Z:\> get-alias echo

CommandType     Name                                               ModuleName                                                                                
-----------     ----                                               ----------                                                                                
Alias           echo -> Write-Output
```

If you look at the [TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849921.aspx) article it does not natively support any append type parameter or newline suppression. That does not mean you can't do it. Just not without any help.

`echo`/`Write-Output` would just be sending data to the output stream. Is there a reason you need your text to do that? Is there by chance a better example you can provide of what you are trying to accomplish? FYI there are other cmdlets at work behind the scenes that being used as well like `Out-Default`

`Write-Host` is really what you want. Yes I am aware you said you didn't want it but I wanted you to see for sure.

```
PS Z:\> Write-host "Hai" -NoNewline; Write-Host "Hello"
HaiHello
```

Comment: # to find users created date and last logon date and upload to .csv  
$users=Get-ADuser -SearchBase "OU=testou1,dc=US,dc=ITOPS,dc=COM" -Filter * -properties samaccountname,lastlogondate,Created  

$forloop = foreach($user in $users) {  
       echo $user.samaccountname  
       echo $user.created  
   echo $user.lastlogondate  
      }  

$forloop | Out-file c:\bin\exporting.csv -Append

Comment: @user2925298 why not just have the one echo line then? `echo "$($user.samaccountname) $($user.created) $($user.lastlogondate)"`?

Comment: thanks its working fine but it is giving in same column. is the any possible way to print in new column of same line

Answer (score 0):

I took the liberty to use some PowerShell features to output the data I think you are actually looking for. I am putting the properties into a custom object and leave output for the end of the script. This makes code reuse easier in the future as you refactor the script. I also used the native CmdLet to export the CSV in the proper format. You don't actually need to use the $forloop variable, because the foreach would put all of the objects into the pipeline, but I left it in because it can make things more readable.

```
 $users=Get-ADuser -SearchBase "OU=testou1,dc=US,dc=ITOPS,dc=COM" -Filter * -properties samaccountname,lastlogondate,Created    
    $forloop = foreach($user in $users) {    
             [pscustomobject]@{
                samaccountname=$user.samaccountname;
                created=$user.created;
                lastlogondate=$user.lastlogondate    
            }
          }    
    $forloop | Export-Csv -Path c:\bin\exporting.csv
```

Comment: while im executing the above script there is no end result.It is like improper running of script continuously without end

Comment: Sorry, I didn't copy the second brace in properly. I corrected it now.

Comment: ya its working fine now. thanks a lot. I am new to powershell.. can you please explain what is  "[pscustomobject]@" used for and why you have given samaccountname=$user.samaccountname;??