# I'm trying to get these two variables out of a function and into a txt or csv file

Tags: powershell

I have an interesting problem. I've created a function to get all the users in an OU and check the last time they logged into to any one of the domain controllers. Now my problem is, i get the correct output in the powershell window, I just cant seem to get the output into a txt or csv file. Any help would be much appreicated

```
$currentdate = Get-Date
$currentdate | Out-File report.txt -Append

function Get-ADUserLastLogon([string]$userName,$array,$datetime)
 {
  $dcs = Get-ADDomainController -Filter {Name -like "*"}
  $time = 0
  foreach($dc in $dcs)
  { 
    $hostname = $dc.HostName
    $user = Get-ADUser $userName | Get-ADObject -Properties lastLogon 
    if($user.LastLogon -gt $time) 
    {
      $time = $user.LastLogon
    }
  }
  $dt = [DateTime]::FromFileTime($time)
  Write-Host $username "last logged on at:" $dt "`n"
}

$users = get-aduser -filter * -SearchBase "ou=Example,dc=Adatum,dc=co,DC=nz" -pr DistinguishedName
$i = 0

write-host "Getting all users in $ou"

while($true)
{
    $i++
    Get-ADUserLastLogon -UserName $users[$i] -array $i
        if($users[$i] -eq $null)
        {
        break
        }
    $usrindex = $i
    $dt | out-file report.txt -Append
    $username | out-file report.txt -Append
}
```

Comment: Answered before (in several ways): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5588689/redirect-write-host-statements-to-file

Comment: Check your code, it seems a bit fishy. You are not using $hostname anywhere, why loop over $dcs at all then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your function, create an array of objects, where each object is of type `System.Object` and has properties of type `NoteProperty` and named after UserName, LastLogon etc. you can then export that array to a CSV easily. See my answer to the following question for an example : [How to use two echo commands to print data on one line using PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29772518/how-to-use-two-echo-commands-to-print-data-on-one-line-using-powershell/29790731#29790731)