# Is there a way to echo multiple objects at once?

Tags: powershell

I want to find out if I could echo multiple objects in powershell. I tried searching this and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29772518/how-to-use-two-echo-commands-to-print-data-on-one-line-using-powershell), but It wasn't what I was looking for.

Basically, I want to be able to echo two different objects (that can both be seen in `foreach-object`) with a single command.

Expected input & output

```
PS C:\> <echo multiple object command> "test" | % {echo "$_ test"}
test test
test test
```

Input and output for what I've tried.

```
PS C:\> echo "test`ntest" | % {echo "$_ test"}
test
test test
```

Expected output:

```
test test
test test
```

If I do this with `get-process` for example, like so:

```
PS C:\> get-process | % {echo "$_ and this"}
```

Output:

```
Process1 (Thing) and this
Process2 (Thing) and this
Process3 (Thing) and this
Process4 (Thing) and this
```

This will also work with arrays like so:

```
PS C:\> $test = @("test1","test2","test3")
PS C:\> $test | % {echo "$_ and this"}
test1 and this
test2 and this
test3 and this
```

**But so far I have not found any way to replicate this with specifying the certain objects other than arrays**

**Summary**: Is there a way to write a multiple object output in powershell 5.1?

So all in all, I want to echo a multi-object output?

Comment: This...    ["test`ntest" | % {echo "$_ test"}]    ...is a single string using a new line, not an array, and thus by design will not list as you are thinking.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "multiple object command" and may be give an example? And explain/show why `Get-Process` is not one of those commands?

Comment: `Get-Process` **is** one of those commands. They output multiple objects that can be interacted with by `ForEach-Object`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-7)

> The ForEach-Object (%) cmdlet performs an operation on each item in a
>   collection of input objects.

And a collection is other words an array So you realy need to feed an array to the foreach (%) cmdlet

Some other examples:

```
@("test1","test2","test3").gettype() # system.array

(get-process).gettype() # system.array

(1..10).gettype() # system.array
1..10 | % {echo "$_ test"}

"test`ntest".Split("`n").gettype() #system array
"test`ntest".Split("`n") | % {echo "$_ test"}
```

in your first example:
echo "test`ntest" | % {echo "$_ test"}

when we check what `(echo "test`ntest").gettype()` is we can see its a System.Object and not an array. so the foreach object will see it as an array with 1 element inside.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the output into a single line by using the `-join` method.

```
($test | % {echo "$_ and this"}) -join ","
# test1 and this,test2 and this,test3 and this
```

If you are interested in printing an array with a single output, you can quote the array to print it with a single command

```
Write-Output "$test"
# test1 test2 test3
```

**what I dont get is** how you expect the following to print anything but.

```
echo "test`ntest" | % {echo "$_ test"}
test
test test
```

Basically you are piping the string (test'ntest) to a foreach object which iterates **only one time** because there is only one string (test'ntest) and then print that (contained within `$_`) with another " test".

Here is another example of how you can print `get-service` with one command (without looping)

```
Write-output (get-service)
```

Answer (score 0):

In short: [You can only send *one* thing to the pipeline at a time.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines?view=powershell-7) Be it a string, an array of strings, or any other object.

What you are asking is not to output multiple objects, but basically just about the way the output is displayed and formatted.

[PowerShell is object-based and not text-based](https://www.itprotoday.com/powershell/powershell-objects-and-output). Displayed output is not content. It has default formats to display objects in a convenient and readable way, even some special formats to display certain object types in a familiar fashion (e.g. file system items).

If I understand correctly, you are trying to display multiple objects "next to each other". This is a very text-oriented approach (not object-oriented). I don't recommend it.

Basically, it's just a formatting question. Ask yourself: How do you expect the output to look like? Then, find a way to do it. Some simple examples were already mentioned in the other answers. You may also want to write a custom [formatting file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_format.ps1xml?view=powershell-7).

In the end, it all depends on your personal preferences. Ask yourself, do you really need it? And why? This might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: This is a good explanation of what should happen. If you give some examples I will mark this as accepted.

Comment: @NekoMusume Examples of what exactly? How can I help? The other answers already give some examples for simple use cases. If you want to create a formatting file, you should read the documentation. I've never created one myself.

Comment: If  you add examples, it will satisfy my question and I believe that this is the best answer so I will accept it if you add examples.